# PHP upgrade from PHP 7.0.4 to PHP 7.0.8 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04, php

I have to upgrade PHP version PHP 7.0.4 to PHP 7.0.8 in order to install third party software which only supported on PHP version 7.0.6 or later.

```
root@A# php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I have used this repository and this doesn't have any PHP version 7.0.6 or later

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php



    root@Anish:/tmp# apt-get update 
    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
    Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
    Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
    Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]        
    Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                           
    Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [244 kB]
    Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [240 kB]
    Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-up

dates/universe amd64 Packages [140 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [137 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [69.9 kB]
Fetched 1,019 kB in 22s (45.2 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
root@Anish:/tmp# php -v 
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
root@Anish:/tmp# apt-cache policy php7.0
php7.0:
  Installed: 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  Candidate: 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  Version table:
 *** 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     7.0.4-7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
root@Anish:/tmp# 



root@Anish:/tmp# /etc/alternatives/php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
root@Anish:/tmp# which php 
/usr/bin/php
root@Anish:/tmp# /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
root@Anish:/tmp#
```

Comment: The repository has PHP 7.0.8 for Xenial. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=xenial

Comment: @DavidFoerster Edited the Question with your comments

Comment: root@Anish:/tmp# readlink "$(which php)"
/etc/alternatives/php
root@Anish:/tmp# which -a php
/usr/bin/php
root@Anish:/tmp#

Comment: root@Anish:/tmp# /etc/alternatives/php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
root@Anish:/tmp# which php 
/usr/bin/php
root@Anish:/tmp# /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
root@Anish:/tmp#

Comment: @DavidFoerster Updated the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple installations of PHP on your system but only one has a command-line interpreter at `/usr/bin/php`.

You need to install the `php7.0-cli` package to replace it with the version from the package repositories. You don't need it to process PHP web pages through a web server, but without it you cannot run the php program. If you still have multiple installations of the `php` program, you should be able to select the default with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```